# what is reason of having error like "String index out of range" in java?

Tags: java

here is my code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);

        String s;


        int i;
        int f=1,c,t=scan.nextInt();


        for(int j=0;j<t;j++)
            {

            s=scan.nextLine();
            scan.close();
            c=s.charAt(0)-s.charAt(1);
            for(i=2;i<s.length()-1;i=i+2)//HERE loop is upto second last element
                {
                if(s.charAt(i)-s.charAt(i+1)!=c && s.charAt(i+1)- s.charAt(i)!=c)
                    {
                    f=0;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(f==1)
                System.out.print("Funny");
            else
                System.out.print("Not Funny");
        }
    }
}
```

**ERROR**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
>       at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
>       at Solution.main(Solution.java:22)

I tried to search on net but I didn't get answer.

Comment: what do you mean what is the purpose of having that error? you're attempting to access something that doesn't exist - e.g. you're if you have a `string s = "hello";` if there is no index "99", what would you expect to happen if you were to attempt to access `s[99]`?

Comment: But I'm not getting out of it.I tried a lot but error is coming always.Can you please point out my error?

Comment: I am not sure exactly what is happening, so forgive me, but are you sure that you are suppoed to add one to i (`s.charAt(i+1)`) in `if(s.charAt(i)-s.charAt(i+1)!=c && s.charAt(i+1)- s.charAt(i)!=c)`? .. our intervals are by two

Comment: yes. I want to add 1 .

Comment: The stacktrace refers to line 22 of `Solution.java`. Which line is line 22?

Comment: In C language this type of logic will run correctly.But why not in java?
In C it will compile and during running of code if we are out of rang then message will appear otherwise code will run correctly.WHY????WHY????

Comment: @MaitreyaPatel Have you looked at either of the proposed duplicates?

Comment: If you think your program will run correctly in C, you have a funny definitionof “correctly” :-) As far as I can tell from this thread, the behaviour in C would not be well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

the error message is telling you where lies the problem. That's the reason of having

> error like “String index out of range” in java

The error message tells you the exception occurs in line 22, which is `c=s.charAt(0)-s.charAt(1);`

and it's out of bound because of 
`String index out of range: 0`, that implies when you are calling `s.charAt(0)`, the length of s is 0, which means s is probably an empty string.